# Error occured while trying to connect with bluetooth module HC-05 connected with arduino in android program

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to exchange the data in between arduino and android phone via bluetooth module `HC-05`, anenter image description hered from 3-4 days I am unable to identify the cased of the following error:

`([JSR82] connect: Connection is not created (failed or aborted).) occurred while try to connect with already paired bluetooth module using its MAC address.`

I also post my `MainActivity.java`, `activity_main.xml` files and the `arduino` code too.

**Main Activity java file :-**

```
package bluetooth.majorproject.bt;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //Button btnScan;
    ListView lvDevices;

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    BluetoothAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;

    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    IntentFilter filter;;

    Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(adapter==null){
            Log.d("Bt","This device doesnot support bluetooth");
            finish();
        }
        else if(!adapter.enable()){
            turnOnBt();
        }

        init();
        getPairedDevices();
        startDiscovery();

    }

    private void init() {
        lvDevices=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvDevices);
       // btnScan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

        listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
        lvDevices.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        startDiscovery();
        pairedDevices=new ArrayList<String>();
        filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
        receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action=intent.getAction();
                if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    Log.d("Bt","Device Found :"+device.getName());
                    String strTmp="";
                    for(int a=0;a<pairedDevices.size();a++){
                        if(device.getAddress().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){
                            strTmp="(Paired)";
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    //PA to writing
                    listAdapter.add(device.getName()+" "+device.getAddress());
                    lvDevices.setAdapter(listAdapter);


                }else  if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                    Log.d("Bt", " Scanning Devices.. ");

                }else  if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                    adapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    if(!devicesArray.isEmpty()){
                        lvDevices.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    }else {
                        Log.d("Bt","Devices Not Found!!");
                    }
                }else  if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                    if(adapter.getState() == adapter.STATE_OFF) {
                        Log.d("Bt","Bluetooth must be enabled to run this app.!!");
                    }

                }
            }
        };

        filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
        filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
        filter=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private void startDiscovery() {
        if(adapter.isDiscovering())
            adapter.cancelDiscovery();
        adapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private void getPairedDevices() {
        devicesArray=adapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(devicesArray.size()>0){
            for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray) {
                pairedDevices.add(device.getName() + " " + device.getAddress());
                listAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
            }
        }
        lvDevices.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

    private void turnOnBt() {
        Intent intent=new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**activity_main xml file :-**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnBTOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000099"
        android:text="Turn Bt On"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Connect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#83FF83"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Connect" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLedOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Turn On Led" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLedOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Turn Off Led" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnBTOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000099"
        android:text="Turn Bt Off"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Arduino Code .ino file:-**

```
/* Bluetooth control of Robot via inputs from Android phone via custom designed android app */

unsigned char myByte = ' ';
int ledPin = 13;
int ledPin2 = 12;
boolean toglVal = HIGH;
unsigned char flag = 0;

// Prior set up of arduino i/0s
void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2,OUTPUT);
  /* ------ define the pins of outputs as per need 
  .
  .
  .
  */

  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.flush();
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.flush();
  if (Serial.available())
  {
  myByte = Serial.read();
  switch(myByte)
  {
    case '1':
    flag = 1;
    break;
    case '0':
    flag = 2;
    break;
    /* ------ define the cases as per the code in android app as per need 
  .
  .
  .
  */

    default:
    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
  }
  }
  while(flag == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin,toglVal);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,~toglVal);
    delay(1000);
    if (Serial.available()) break;   
  }
  while(flag == 2)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,toglVal);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ledPin,~toglVal);
    delay(500);
    if (Serial.available()) break;
  }
 }
```

Someone please help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using a while loop in your main loop(). While will not let the program execute next instruction unless your condition inside the while satisfies. It will keep on waiting there. It will enter into and infinite while loop and never come out. Consider using an **if() loop** for the same.

Comment: thanks for reply.
I also try this but it does not solve my problem.